# Segfault when passing array to C++ function

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function to read an array from a binary file in C++. This is my function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
int bread(T array_out[], int array_size, const char FILENAME[]) {
    // Open file
    std::ifstream input_file (FILENAME, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary
            | std::ios::ate);
    // Check that the file was opened correctly
    if (input_file.is_open()) {
        // Check that the file size matches the array size
        std::streampos file_size = input_file.tellg();
        if (file_size == array_size) {
            // Read the array contents from the file
            input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&array_out), array_size);
            // Close file
            input_file.close();
        } else {
            std::cerr << "File " << FILENAME << " is not of expected size.\n";
            std::cerr << "  File size:\t" << file_size << " B\n";
            std::cerr << "  Expected\t" << array_size << " B\n";
            // Close file
            input_file.close();
            return -2;
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file " << FILENAME << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without the `| std::ios::ate`, this calculates a file size of 0 and returns `-2`. That makes sense.

But as soon as I include `| std::ios::ate` (or, as an alternative, `input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);`), execution of the function fails with a segfault. Clearly seeking within the file works in some cases, since `input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);` works as expected.

My guess is that there might be no EOF marker in the input file. If that's the case, is there some way to handle that safely?

**Edit:** The function is called here:

```
int verify_buff[SIZE];
Ierr = bread(verify_buff, sizeof(verify_buff), "serial.bin");
if (Ierr != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Error " << Ierr << " in function bread\n";
    return Ierr;
}
```

where `SIZE` is a global constant defined as 1024.

At segfault,

```
array_size = 4096
array_out = 0x7ffd5dca20e0
```

Full segfault message:

```
[physlogin:81411] *** Process received signal ***
[physlogin:81411] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[physlogin:81411] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[physlogin:81411] Failing at address: 0x1
[physlogin:81411] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3cb300f7e0]
[physlogin:81411] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(fclose+0x4)[0x3cb2466344]
[physlogin:81411] [ 2] /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt12__basic_fileIcE5closeEv+0x4c)[0x3cb78ba5ac]
[physlogin:81411] [ 3] /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv+0xb7)[0x3cb786cb77]
[physlogin:81411] [ 4] /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv+0xd)[0x3cb786ebfd]
[physlogin:81411] [ 5] Q3_gw639.exe[0x40dec5]
[physlogin:81411] [ 6] Q3_gw639.exe[0x40ea06]
[physlogin:81411] *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: EOF is not part of the file in any case. It's a signal from the OS that there is nothing more to read, there is no "EOF marker" physically present in a file. Anyway, a complete example to reproduce the problem would have been nice. Which statement segfaults, exactly?

Comment: What are `array_out` and `array_size` defined to when it segfaults?

Comment: @DevSolar I've tried to make the example as complete as possible; the entire function is here, so I'm not sure what more I could provide short of uploading my entire source file (which I'd happily do, but the rest of it is irrelevant) or the 4096 B binary file, but I'll happily provide any additional information you need.

Comment: @DevSolar array_size: 4096; array_out: 0x7ffddb177010

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... For example, either the values of `array_out` and `array_size` matter (and you should have included them), or they don't (then they shouldn't be in the example). If the problem is really about reading the file position, then we don't need the reading-into-the-array at all. Have you tried removing that part to see if it still segfaults? "Complete" would mean I can copy, compile, and execute your example and see the same problem you are observing.

Comment: @dendodge *the entire function is here,* -- A function by itself does nothing.  It requires a caller, along with the necessary parameters.  Note that your parameters requires pointers, and we have no idea if those pointers are valid, etc.  Anyone can "segfault" your function by providing bad parameters -- that's why we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: All that being said, I get goosebumps looking at the templated array and the reading into it via `reinterpret_cast<char *>`...

Comment: @dendodge `input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&array_out), array_size);` -- That first parameter is mighty suspicious.  Why are you passing the address of a pointer?  And what exactly is `T` in your actual code?  If it's a non-POD type, none of this will work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nice catch.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's definitely a POD type, I'm only using it for `int`s (at the moment). I'm using `reinterpret_cast` primarily because it's the only thing that seemed to work, but it does feel very hacky and unpleasant, and I'd love to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major issue is your call to `read` here:

```
 input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&array_out), array_size);
```

Since `array_out` is already a `T*`, this line attempts to read into an address of the pointer.  This is incorrect -- what you want to do is this:

```
 input_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(array_out), array_size);
```

---

Please note that your function declaration:

```
template <typename T>
int bread(T array_out[], int array_size, const char FILENAME[])
```

is no different than this one:

```
template <typename T>
int bread(T* array_out, int array_size, const char* FILENAME)
```

Even though the first one looks like it is receiving an array, it isn't.  Passing an array by name decays the parameter being passed to a pointer, thus you were dealing with pointers within the function.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: @dendodge: ...which means the whole question, while useful to you, is not useful to anybody else because it's not at all about "seeking to end of binary file"... (Not intending any offence, just trying to point out how to isolate problems / ask better questions in future.)

Comment: @DevSolar Yeah, whoops. I did try to isolate the cause, but I'm aware I did a pretty terrible job. Perhaps I should retitle the question for the sake of future generations. I'm better at tracking down issues in languages I know better, like Fortran, but C++ (especially its handling of arrays and pointers) is still mostly a magic box to me so it's hard to know what's relevant to the problem at hand. I've learnt a lot about the workings of the language through this debacle though, so I'd like to genuinely thank you for your help.

Comment: @dendodge: C++ is my 9-to-5 language... one more bit of advice: If done right, you shouldn't *need* arrays and pointers in C++. (There's references and `std::vector` and `std::array` and `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to wrap those C-isms...)